# li menu needs class of "selected"

Tags: jquery, css, menu, html-lists

when the user clicks on a menu tab i want it to remain selected with it a white button.

here is my attempt but its not working. if you click the home button it doesnt remain white.

**html**

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/en-us/about.aspx"><span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/en-us/contact.aspx"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
body{
    background-color:orange;
}

#navigation a
{
    background: url("http://i52.tinypic.com/spxfdw.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #000000;
    height: 43px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 116px;
}

#navigation a span
{
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#navigation a, #navigation a span
{
    display: block;
    float: left;

}

/* Hide from IE5-Mac \*/
#navigation a, #navigation a span
{
    float: none
}
/* End hide */

#navigation a:hover
{

    background: url('http://i51.tinypic.com/2iih9c9.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #000000;
    height: 43px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 116px;
    text-align:center
}

#navigation a:hover span
{
    background: url(right-tab-hover.gif) right top no-repeat;
    padding-right: 10px
}

#navigation ul
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

#navigation li
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#navigation li').click(function() {
    $('#navigation li').addClass('selected');
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: because i never receive a working solution..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see several modifications here.

Firstly, when you apply selected class, you are applying to all `li` items, which is not true. you only want to apply the class to clicked list item.

secondly, when you click another list item, you want to remove the selected class.

so the code modified would be:

```
$('#navigation li').click(function() {
    $('#navigation li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Most importantly, you do not have a `selected` class. I put a temporary selected class definition like so:

```
.selected{
border: 1px solid #888;
background-color: #white;
```

}

You can see a working example here: [on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anKT3/1/)

**additionally**, your `a` element has a gray background. so you might want to apply selected white background class to your a element also.. something like:

```
$('a', this).addClass('selected'); //apply to  anchor element also
```

and when you remove the class, follow the same deal.

So you want to persist the button states across different Pages. Javascript is only valid as long as the page is open. As soon as the user goes to the new page, all javascript will be reset. To overcome this you can do one of these two things:

1) If you are using a master page for menu, add `runat="server"` attribute to your list items, and from code behind, add selected class to appropriate list item from your child page (may be you could have a public function in your Master page)

```
    //Master page
    public SetHomeMenu()
    {
        liHome.Attributes.Add("class","selected");
    }

    //in Child page
    Master.SetHomeMenu();
```

2) If you want to do it in javascript, you need to read your url, parse it, then add `selected` class to appropriate `li`

```
//put this javascript in your head section or even at the bottom, just before closing
// body tag </body>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("home"))
        {
             $("#navigation li#home").addClass("selected");
        }
        else if(window.location.href.indexOf("about"))
        {
             $("#navigation li#about").addClass("selected");
        }
        else if(window.location.href.indexOf("contact"))
        {
             $("#navigation li#contact").addClass("selected");
        } 

    });
```

But for this to work, you need to add `id` attributes to your list items like so:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li id="home"><a href="#"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="/en-us/about.aspx"><span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="/en-us/contact.aspx"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

For use the last solution you need to change the if statement to this example:

> if(window.location.href.indexOf("home") > -1)

Comment: ok i can just view source on your example. Once i click the link it doesnt keep the tab selected.

Comment: @PD24: updated to jsfiddle. can you explain what you mean by saying when you click it doesn't stay? are you redirecting your user to a new page?

Comment: yes, when they click the home page they might be on another page within the site. therefore the tab needs to be selected with the appropriate CSS when clicked and sent to the page.

Comment: Okay, you need some fundamental understanding of how page works. I will edit my answer. wait for it.

Comment: I understand that when the class is applyed it gets scrubbed when the new page is loaded. I assume i need to look at the URL using jquery to apply the class again.. but i dont know how..

Comment: i like javascript method for now. but it appears that the home li is always selected.. even though i click on the about link

Comment: @PD2F: okay, sure you can use js, if your home is always selected, make sure you are not adding the class anywhere else. Also, you should probably remove your first javascript block ``$().click{}...`` as it's no longer doing anything..

Comment: yeah ive removed that. a friend of mine says i should append the tab id to the querystring and then use jquery to read the values.. is that what you did? my url looks like this: http://sub.mysite.co.uk/en-us/home.aspx

Comment: you **may** do that, but, honestly, it's not necessary at all, as you have the rest of the url anyway. Can you give me the url to your contact page? (or atleast a similar looking one) then I will be able to find out what it is like. thanks.

Comment: its the same, just has contact.aspx on the end.

Comment: i changed my a href to this: /en-us/home.aspx?SelectedTabID=tab1

Comment: okay, with the code above, you seriously do not need ``selectedTabId=tab1`` bit at all. I suspect your home element has been assigned the selected class from within, Can I have a link to your page if possible?

Comment: @iamserious-I have the same problem in the menu

Comment: Bravo! indexOf is about the first lesson when on study Js! ahahah easy! thanks

Answer (score 1):

This'd do it.  You forgot to set the selected class css

http://fiddle.jshell.net/54uDQ/

The important part is this css

```
#navigation a:hover, #navigation a.selected
{

    background: url('http://i51.tinypic.com/2iih9c9.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #000000;
    height: 43px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 116px;
    text-align:center
}
```

Comment: please can you save the project and paste the link here.. as it didnt show up

Comment: @Jospeh: it works in JSfiddle but on my page when i click the tab it doesnt keep the selected class. I need it to keep the selected class so that the user knows what page they are on.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated you dont have a .selected class also your js will set all li elements to selected when one is clicked you may want to change it to this on the second line

```
$('#navigation  li').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#navigation li.a.seletected a.seletected 
{
    background: white; // or background Image or whatever it is your doing to make this      white.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't even set a class for 'selected' in your CSS.

Add this and it should work.

```
#navigation li .selected {
   [CSS to make white background here.]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't remain selected? If you link to another page, you're going to need to apply the class to that tab again on the next page: classes are not persistent through all pages when you set it on one page with jQuery.

Comment: so when the user clicks on [home] and they are on the [about] page.. i would expect the [HOME] tab to be selected and shown in white.

Comment: It would, until the new page loads. At that point, you need it to set again when the new page loads up via a cookie, PHP, jQuery, however you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your CSS, you haven't defined any styles for the `selected` class.

Assigning that class to your li isn't enough. You also need to style the class in the way you'd like.

```
.selected{
 background-color:#fff;
}
```

(etc)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have no css for '.selected'. So, add the styling to turn the button white.
2. Your jQuery is incorrect. In the click function, target 'this' because that targets the specific element that you clicked.

   ```
   $('#navigation li').click(function(event) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
   });
   ```