# How to toggle between active classes in twitter bootstrap on li's?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following header that will toggle between pages:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form method="post">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="active.php">Active Tags</a></li>
          <li><a href="archived.php">Archived Tags</a></li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and the following jQuery to toggle the active li on click:

```
$('.navbar li').click(function(e) {
  $('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Moving between pages works only when `e.preventDefault();` is commented out but the active class toggle won't work without this line... will I have to change my `href's` to sometype of `onclick jQuery function` or `php $_POST` of a hidden form to move between pages while retaining the toggle between `active li's`? Am new to javascript/html/php so as much detail and reasoning as possible is quite encouraged and encouraging.

Comment: Move e.preventDefault(); to top of the event handler, and then try.

Comment: I think the e.preventDefault() keeps the href link from working at all, at least moving it to the top of the function does not work..

Comment: Can you navigation contain other links as well? Or just these two.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, `e.preventDefault()` will just toggle active class on li and restrict anchor to perform its operation.

While, changing it to `e.stopPropagation()` will allow both operation to perform at their own, without notifying regarding their event to parent handler.

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Therefore, you can change it to:

```
$('.navbar li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/parkashkumar37/fxo86mz1/)

Comment: This allows the page navigation to work but unfortunately the default active class still shows up.

Comment: Is your header similar for pages you navigate?

Comment: exactly the same in every page

Comment: Do you have included header file on each page you navigate or using some kind of template that will include header?

Comment: I have a default header page and place it in each page navigated to via <?php include("header.php")?>

Comment: So, you need to do pass dynamic classes through server-side if you have redirection.

Comment: ok so what would that look like? Could I use $_POST on a hidden value in the header form or is there a better, more standard way to do this?

Comment: You need to check for current page link and add active class to respective li.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873348/li-menu-needs-class-of-selected#answer-6873618