# Move selected attribute in html list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

If I have a list like this, how do I make it so that if I click on one of the unselected item links that it moves the `class="active"` to that list item instead and removes it from the old one?

**Before:**

```
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**After clicking on the third link:**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<li selected>` isn't valid. Did you mean `<li class="selected">` or `<li data-selected="true">`?

Comment: Was going to post the same thing. The selected attribute is normally used in the option element inside of a select element.

Comment: yes, you are right, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use classes. So :

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

also see this post for further support.  It's close [li menu needs class of "selected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873348/li-menu-needs-class-of-selected)

Jquery: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I think they will be clicking the link though - or does that not matter?

Comment: A click on the link would bubble up to the parent `<li>` unless you prevent it using `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather simple. When a `<li>` is clicked then add the class to the clicked element and remove it from the one that currently has it.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
});
```

In this code when a `<li>` is clicked that element is given the `active` class and then we find the sibling element that currently has the class and remove the class.